# query documentDB inner level without knowing outer level

Tags: c#, json, azure-cosmosdb

I have a json file as a document in documentDB and I have a collection of this type of document. I want to query the collection to get all document where "unit"= "Hrs". The sku and offerTermCode varies product by product and I am not able to know all of them. I am not sure how to do the query. Is there is a way to solve this problem? Thanks in advance!

Update: Another way I am thinking is to modify the json before upload to documentDB:
I deserialize the json file and get a JToken type for each product. My question in this approach is how can I change the "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ" to a string I want and how can I change priceDimensions to a list without the key
"DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U"?

```
{

     "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ" : {
          "offerTermCode" : "HU7G6KETJZ",
          "sku" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF",
          "effectiveDate" : "2017-02-28T23:59:59Z",
          "priceDimensions" : {
            "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U" : {
              "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.2TG2D8R56U",
              "description" : "Upfront Fee",
              "unit" : "Quantity",
              "pricePerUnit" : {
                "USD" : "11213"
              },
              "appliesTo" : [ ]
            },
            "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7" : {
              "rateCode" : "DQ578CGN99KG6ECF.HU7G6KETJZ.6YS6EN2CT7",
              "description" : "Windows (Amazon VPC), hs1.8xlarge instance-hours used this month",
              "beginRange" : "0",
              "endRange" : "Inf",
              "unit" : "Hrs",
              "pricePerUnit" : {
                "USD" : "1.2510000000"
              },
              "appliesTo" : [ ]
            }
          },
          "termAttributes" : {
            "LeaseContractLength" : "1yr",
            "OfferingClass" : "standard",
            "PurchaseOption" : "Partial Upfront"
          }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not that this answers your question, but you used values as your keys, which makes things pretty much impossible to query efficiently. Rather than `somevalue: {subdocument content}`, consider something like `id: somevalue, someSubdocumentGroup: {subdocument content}`

Comment: I am sorry I don't quite understand your answer. Do you mean I need to modify the json/document?

Comment: It's not really an answer. I'm pointing out that your JSON is not set up as key:value pairs. You used `DQ57...` as a key, but it should be a value.  So yes, I'm suggesting you modify your JSON documents (and I gave an example of how to alter it in my prior comment). You need to correct your data modeling.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer!